# Tips-Help for a Nested Form using has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I'm learning ruby on rails and this is my second question in SO. I'm making a DB to manage products. In part of my squema I have users that can have many brands, and brands that can have many users. I want to do a nested form for creating a new user(sign up) that have a field for entering the user brand name that is used to create a brand object associated to that user.

So my squema looks like this:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  .
  .
  .
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :brands
  .
  .
  .
end
```

---

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160614163029) do

  create_table "brands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "brands_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "brand_id"
  end

  add_index "brands_users", ["brand_id"], name: "index_brands_users_on_brand_id"
  add_index "brands_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_brands_users_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Im trying to add the field for adding the brand name via a nested form in my user creation form with no success.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name, "Nombre:" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email, "Correo Electrónico:" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password, "Contraseña:" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmación de Contraseña:" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.fields_for :brands do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.label :name, "Nombre de tu Marca:" %>
        <%= ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit "Crear Cuenta", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This form is only forming the text fields for the form for user.
I'm a little bit lost. Any help will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really used `f.fields_for` for nested attributes. At YesInsights, I use [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) with [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). These libraries make it really easy to make a form with nested attributes -- you can even add links to add more brands to a user right in the form with a simple helper.

Comment: Actually, I just realized, your fields aren't showing up because you don't have any Brand objects associated with your User. In your controller, add `user.brands.build`. That said, I'd still highly recommend Simple Form and Cocoon.

Comment: In the get part of the controller or in the post of the form?

Comment: @Bambi'sDilemma I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking where you would use Cocoon/Simple Form?

Comment: no, where to put user.brands.build in my controller but I figured out! Thanks a lot!